# Solr search on concatenated text

Tags: solr, filter, full-text-search, concatenation, grouping

I would like to make a **Solr query**, which would for data like
`{ "date": ..., "project": ..., "text": ... }`
do in order:

1. Filter them by date range
2. Group by project, so that I get single row per project with text concatenated
3. On top of this, do full-text search, with things like some word there is in the concatenated text or it isn't

As a result, I want to get projects for which related texts(for each project all texts concatenated from given date range) contain/don't contain some phrases (depending on a query parameter).

I need to have documents separated so I can filter them by date range, but after filtering I need to concatenate them by project field, so I can make a full-text search query on them as if I would keep whole text for given project together.

I was able to find that for related things it's possible to do something like:

1. `&fq=date:[2013-07-17T00:00:00Z TO 2013-07-20T00:00:00Z]`
2. -
3. `&q=+text:mars-text:venus`

I don't know how to do the 2., and how to do 3. so that it's applied to the concatenated texts (at the end). I found that there's some grouping feature but I don't know how to concatenate the text in each group, so I get single entry per group to apply 3. on it.

Is it possible to do such query in Solr? How should it be properly done if it's possible? If no, is it possible to do it effectively with something different than Solr?

Thanks for help.

Comment: Exactly what problem are you trying to solve? What is the reason for having the content concatenated? It might be better to index projects as single documents with all associated text if you're searching for projects and not the contents of each document in that project.

Comment: I added a description of expected result and why I need them stored separated and concatenated for full-text search. Are you suggesting something something like:

Comment: { "project": ..., [
    { "date": ..., "text":... },
 { "date": ..., "text":... }
]}
?
In this format I woudl have to concatenate text anyways, and updating of such thing seems to be less eficient.
Would you describe more what you have in mind please? Thanks!

Comment: So you're trying to find projects that have "foo" but not "bar" _within_ a time interval (so if bar is present in project outside of the time fq, it shouldn't be considered)?

Comment: Exactly. Depending on query params, it can be for which have foo, or for which have foo but not bar, or that just don't have bar.